# Can't parse JSONB scalar as array in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm on PostgreSQL 13.2. I have a table with a JSONB column, and it stores JSONs that are a list of objects:

```json
"[{\"MyKey\":\"ValueXYZ\",\"Counter\":0}, {\"MyKey\":\"ValueABC\",\"Counter\":3}]"
```

When I test this column for a type with `jsonb_typeof()` like so:

```sql
select jsonb_typeof(i.my_column) as col_type
from items i 
where i.id = 342
```

I get `string`. Which tells me this value is a scalar, and I'm wondering if maybe it wasn't inserted properly.

The error that is bothering me is I am trying to parse the column with something like this:

```sql
select jsonb_array_elements(i.my_column)
from items i
```

and I see the error:

```
SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar
```

What is going on? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it got inserted wrong.  It contains a scalar, which happens to be holding the string representation of a JSON array.  The string representation of a JSON array is a different thing than an actual JSON array.

You can extract the string value from the scalar, then cast that string into a jsonb.  `#>>'{}'` will extract the string out of a scalar.

```
select jsonb_array_elements((i.my_column#>>'{}')::jsonb)
from items i ;
```

Although you should fundamentally fix the problem, by re-storing the values correctly.

```
update items set my_column = (my_column#>>'{}')::jsonb where jsonb_typeof(my_column)='string';
```

But of course you should fix whatever is doing the incorrect insertions first.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a quoting issue. Consider:

```
test=> SELECT jsonb_typeof(jsonb '[{"MyKey":"ValueXYZ","Counter":0}, {"MyKey":"ValueABC","Counter":3}]') AS col_type;
 col_type 
----------
 array
(1 row)
```